# replace only integer values in columns and use pd.cut to rename values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer

I have pandas dataframe 'lc' and want to replace only integer values to string.

```
            indexsum
    82445    start
    82446    start
    82447    start
    82448       11
    82449       10
    82450       12
    82451       12
    82452        9
    82453       11
    82454        9
    82455       10
    82456       10
    82457        9
    82458        9
    82459        9
```

I have compe up with using pd.cut method and write code like this, but error message showed up. It seemed like I can not use this code if I have string and integer values in the same column. What function do I have to use? (instead of mapping method)

```
 lc['lcindex'] = pd.cut(lc.indexsum, bins=[0,4,8,12,16], labels=["growth","mature","revival","decline"])

 TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerece'`:

```
df['lc'] = pd.cut(pd.to_numeric(df.indexsum, errors='coerce'),bins=[-np.inf,0,4,8,12,16], labels=["start","growth","mature","revival","decline"]).fillna('start')
```

Output:

```
      indexsum       lc
82445    start    start
82446    start    start
82447    start    start
82448       11  revival
82449       10  revival
82450       12  revival
82451       12  revival
82452        9  revival
82453       11  revival
82454        9  revival
82455       10  revival
82456       10  revival
82457        9  revival
82458        9  revival
82459        9  revival
```

Comment: i think `.fillna(df.indexsum)` would be bit more robust as OP might have different strings (not only `start`) :)

Comment: I don't this will work because pd.cut returns category dtype and those others might return a string not in labels.

Comment: that's a good point, thank you! We can add `.astype('category')` at the end - this would cast that series back to `category` dtype

Answer (score 2):

we can use [to_numeric(..., errors='coerce')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) method:

```
In [186]: lc['lcindex'] = pd.cut(pd.to_numeric(lc.indexsum, errors='coerce'),
     ...:                        bins=[0,4,8,12,16],
     ...:                        labels=["growth","mature","revival","decline"]) \
                            .combine_first(lc.indexsum) \
                            .astype('category')

In [187]: lc
Out[187]:
      indexsum  lcindex
82445    start    start
82446    start    start
82447    start    start
82448       11  revival
82449       10  revival
82450       12  revival
82451       12  revival
82452        9  revival
82453       11  revival
82454        9  revival
82455       10  revival
82456       10  revival
82457        9  revival
82458        9  revival
82459        9  revival
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question! What if I want to keep values 'start' in indexsum into lcindex so I do not have any Nan values in lcindex columns?

Comment: @TTaa, please check Scott Boston's answer :)